# How can I convert from HDF (Harmonized Landsat and Sentinel-2 product) to TIFF in R?

Tags: r, tiff, sentinel, hdf, landsat

I am a beginner in R and now I am working in the product at NASA: Harmonized Landsat and Sentinel-2. I downloaded the image in .hdf, but when I tried to convert in R to tiff, received an error.

I'm using this code:

---

```
library(gdalUtils)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
gdal_setInstallation(verbose=TRUE)
getOption("gdalUtils_gdalPath")


setwd(dir = "C:/Users/HOME/Documents/TESTE")
getwd()

sds <- get_subdatasets('HLS.L30.T23LLG.2016004.v1.3.hdf')
sds

gdal_translate(sds[1], dst_dataset = "band1.tif", a_nodata = -1000)
```

---

**This is the error:**

> ***Warning message:***
>
> running command
>   '"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\Library\bin\gdal_translate.exe" -a_nodata
>   "-1000" -of "GTiff" "782" "band1.tif"' had status 1

---

The image can be downloaded here: https://hls.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/v1.3/sites/BAH/L30/2016/23LLG/

Comment: What is `teste[1]`?

Comment: I'm sorry, it should be sds[1] there.

Comment: That's just an error your *post* (not the code you're running), correct? :)

Comment: Yes, I'm using the fuction gdal_translate in R to convert the image sds[1] from hdf to tiff.